# Does google analytics count Ajax request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-analytics

On document ready I use this script

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url:"http://www.other_web_site.com/",
    type:'POST',
    success: function(data) {
       // do nothing
    }
})
```

www.other_web_site.com is using google analytics. google analytics will note +1 visit ?

if no so how can I let him know ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Analytics will count it. However, it should be requested as you described, in-which, all page is accessed.

Comment: If I request "http://www.other_web_site.com/" as AJAX, jQuery will only retrieve the HTML. How, then, can the other website notify Google Analytics, which is loaded by JavaScript?

Answer (score 3):

In heavily JavaScript dependent Web Applications, it isn't able to gather complete information about AJAX events, but there are tutorials available about how to manually push data to Google Analytics to track such events.

[This Tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/google-analytics-track-javascript-ajax-events/) may be useful.

Additionally, [this article](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/) from Google explains more about how to wire up tracking AJAX events (See Pushing Functions).